# Aplicar la función XOR a dos archivos

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber como puedo leer un par de archivos, con cualquier tipo de contenido (texto, numeros, etc) y que pueda aplicarles la función XOR a estos dos archivos. Alguien sabe como podría hacer eso? Me gustaría implementarlo en python o java.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con aplicar la función XOR ? ¿Quieres hacer XOR usando el primer byte de un archivo con el primero del otro y así sucesivamente?, ¿tienen los archivos el mismo numero de bytes?, ¿o en vez de hacer XOR entre ellos usas una clave?. Aporta algo de más información para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El operador para bitwise **xor** en `Java` es `^`. Desde Java7 leer un archivo en un arreglo de bytes queda muy simple, así si no tienes archivos muy grandes puedes leer los dos archivos completos en un arreglo de bytes y escribir la comparación en un nuevo arreglo de bytes:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;


public class XorFiles {

public static byte[] xorFiles(File uno, File dos) throws IOException{
        byte[] byteUno = Files.readAllBytes(uno.toPath());
        byte[] byteDos = Files.readAllBytes(dos.toPath());
        // podemos comparar hasta el tamaño minimo de los dos archivos
        byte[] xorUnoDos = new byte[Math.min(byteUno.length, byteDos.length)];
        for (int i = 0;i<xorUnoDos.length;i++){
            // bitwise xor operador: ^
            xorUnoDos[i] = (byte) (byteUno[i] ^ byteDos[i]);
        }
        return xorUnoDos;
    }

}

// uso
byte[] resultado = XorFiles.xorFiles(new File("data/uno.bin"), new File("data/dos.bin") );
```

Obviamente la comparación se puede hacer hasta el tamaño del archivo más corto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, funciona perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba. @Stefan